# validar array con un request laravel

Tags: laravel, validación

estoy trabajando en un formulario con una tabla en la cual genero filas con inputs de forma dinamica, necesito validar un par de inputs de esta tabla dinamica (es decir que estos inputs sean requeridos), tengo mi request en el cual tengo la regla de validacion para los demas campos del formulario pero al hacer el store se salta la validacion de los inputs dinamicos y hace el insert igual jeje...

Tengo dudas como declarar estos inputs dinamicos en el request, por el momento lo tengo asi el request pero no me funcionado:

```
  public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'nombres' => 'required|max:50',
            'ape_pat' => 'required|max:50',
            'ape_mat' => 'required|max:50',
            'rut' => 'required|max:25',
            'institucion' => 'required',
            'cargo' => 'required',
            'unidad' => 'required',
            'jornada' => 'required',
            'telefono' => 'required|max:9',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:90',
            'fecha_realizacion_visita' => 'required',
            'hora_ingreso' => 'required',
            'hora_salida' => 'required',
            'movilizacion' => 'required',
            'motivo_visita' => 'required',
            'nombres_asistente' => 'required|array',
            'ape_pat_asistente' => 'required|array',
            'rut_asistente' => 'required|array',
            'telefono_asistente' => 'required|array',



        ];
    }

    public function messages(){

        return[

            'nombres.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Su nombre(s)',
            'nombres.max' =>'Maximo 50 caracteres',
            'ape_pat.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Apellido Paterno',
            'ape_pat.max' =>'Maximo 50 caracteres',
            'rut.required' =>'Debe Ingresar N° Rut o Doc.Identidad',
            'institucion.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Institución',
            'cargo.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Cargo',
            'unidad.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Unidad',
            'jornada.required' =>'Debe Seleccionar Jornada',
            'telefono.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Telefono (Ej:911223344)',
            'telefono.max' =>'Maximo 9 numeros',
            'email.required' =>'Debe Ingresar Correo Electronico',
            'email.max' =>'Maximo 90 caracteres',
            'email.email'=> 'Formato de Email no valido',
            'fecha_realizacion_visita.required' =>'Debe Seleccionar Fecha de la Visita',
            'hora_ingreso.required' =>'Debe indicar Hora de Acceso',
            'hora_salida.required' =>'Debe indicar Hora de Salida',
            'movilizacion.required' =>'Debe Indicar si requiere movilizacion',
            'motivo_visita.required' =>'Debe Seleccionar Motivo Visita',

            'nombres_asistente[].required' => 'Nombre del Asistente es Obligatorio',
            'ape_pat_asistente[].required' => 'Apellido Paterno del Asistente es Obligatorio',
            'rut_asistente[].required' => 'Rut del Asistente es Obligatorio',
            'telefono_asistente[].required' => 'Telefono del Asistente es Obligatorio'
        ];
    }
```

y el blade donde tengo el formulario:

```
 <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-3">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fecha_realizacion_visita">Fecha Realización Visita*</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control @error('fecha_realizacion_visita') is-invalid @enderror" name="fecha_realizacion_visita" value="{{old('fecha_realizacion_visita')}}" id="fecha_realizacion_visita">
                                @error('fecha_realizacion_visita')
                                    <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="hora_ingreso">Hora Ingreso*</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control @error('hora_ingreso') is-invalid @enderror" name="hora_ingreso" value="{{old('hora_ingreso')}}" id="hora_ingreso">
                                @error('hora_ingreso')
                                    <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="hora_salida">Hora Salida*</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control @error('hora_salida') is-invalid @enderror" name="hora_salida" value="{{old('hora_salida')}}" id="hora_salida">
                                @error('hora_salida')
                                    <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="movilizacion">Requiere Movilización*</label>
                                <select name="movilizacion" id="movilizacion" class="form-control @error('movilizacion') is-invalid @enderror">
                                    <option value="NO" selected>NO</option>
                                    <option value="SI" {{ old('movilizacion') == "SI" ? 'selected' : '' }}>SI</option>
                                </select>
                                @error('movilizacion')
                                    <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2" id="oculto">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fecha_movilizacion">Fecha Movilización</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control @error('fecha_movilizacion') is-invalid @enderror" name="fecha_movilizacion" value="{{old('fecha_movilizacion')}}" id="fecha_movilizacion">
                                @error('fecha_movilizacion')
                                    <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2" id="movilizacion_propia_div">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="movilizacion_propia">Movilización Propia?</label>
                                <select name="movilizacion_propia" id="movilizacion_propia" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" selected disabled>-SELECCIONE-</option>
                                    <option value="SI">SI</option>
                                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-sm pull-right" type="button" >SIGUIENTE ></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <p><strong>(Es obligatoria la presentación de los antecedentes y fundamentación de la visita al Hospital de Quellón, debe adjuntar respaldo de documentos necesarios a esta solicitud)</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--ASISTENTES-->
                <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                <p><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Si requiere añadir mas de un asistente presioné el botón “Añadir”.</p>
                              </div>
                   @if (count($errors) > 0)
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-12">
                                      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                                          @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                          {{ $error }} <br>
                                          @endforeach
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            @endif
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>NOMBRES</th>
                                    <th>APELLIDO PATERNO</th>
                                    <th>APELLIDO MATERNO</th>
                                    <th>RUT</th>
                                    <th>TELÉFONO</th>
                                    <th>CORREO ELECTRONICO</th>
                                    <th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary add">Añadir</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="nombres_asistente[]" placeholder="Escriba Nombre(s)" class="form-control @error('nombres_asistente') is-invalid @enderror"  />

                                        @error('nombres_asistente')
                                        <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="ape_pat_asistente[]" placeholder="Escriba Apellido Paterno" class="form-control @error('ape_pat_asistente') is-invalid @enderror"  />
                                        @error('ape_pat_asistente')
                                        <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="ape_mat_asistente[]" placeholder="Escriba Apellido Materno" class="form-control" /></td>

                                    <td><input type="text" name="rut_asistente[]" placeholder="Escriba Rut/Documento" class="form-control @error('rut_asistente') is-invalid @enderror"  />
                                        @error('rut_asistente')
                                        <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="telefono_asistente[]" placeholder="Escriba Teléfono" class="form-control @error('telefono_asistente') is-invalid @enderror" />
                                        @error('telefono_asistente')
                                        <small class="text text-danger"><strong>*{{$message}}</strong></small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="email_asistente[]" placeholder="Escriba Email" class="form-control" /></td>
                                    <th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger dlt">Quitar</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Generar Solicitud</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

  </main>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js" integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    // Añadir/quitar filas
    $('thead').on('click', '.add', function(){
        var tr = "<tr>"+
                    "<td><input type='text' name='nombres_asistente[]' placeholder='Escriba Nombre(s)' class='form-control @error('nombres_asistente') is-invalid @enderror'  /></td>"+
                    "<td><input type='text' name='ape_pat_asistente[]' placeholder='Escriba Apellido Paterno' class='form-control @error('ape_pat_asistente') is-invalid @enderror'  /></td>"+
                    "<td><input type='text' name='ape_mat_asistente[]' placeholder='Escriba Apellido Materno' class='form-control' /></td>"+
                    "<td><input type='text' name='rut_asistente[]' placeholder='Escriba Rut/Documento' class='form-control @error('rut_asistente') is-invalid @enderror'  /></td>"+
                    "<td><input type='text' name='telefono_asistente[]' placeholder='Escriba Teléfono' class='form-control @error('telefono_asistente') is-invalid @enderror' /></td>"+
                    "<td><input type='text' name='email_asistente[]' placeholder='Escriba Email' class='form-control' /></td>"+
                    "<th><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger dlt'>Quitar</a></th>"+

                    "</tr>"

                $('tbody').append(tr);

    });

    $('tbody').on('click', '.dlt', function(){

        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

    });
```

Saludos a todos y gracias por cualquier observacion de que me puede estar fallando

Answer (score 0):

Con los campos que sean dinámicos, prueba agregando un .* luego del nombre del campo en tu validation rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nombres_asistente.*' => 'required,
    ];
}
```

Igual tendrás que hacerlo con los messages para transformarlos a todos.

Espero que te sirva!